# Sysinfo parser for a window manager status bar

Tags: c, parsing, linux, status-monitoring, x11

The program is written mainly for the status bar in dwm (a window manager for Linux), but it can be used for any manager that takes input from the root window in X. It queries different resources in the computer and displays the formatted information in the status bar.

This is a full, tested, ready-and-waiting program. Here is the main repository for the code: [dwm-statusbar](https://github.com/snhilde/dwm-statusbar/tree/c55bc81d513379f2da0d97da54887147b226d0a7)

I am looking for others to review my code and give me any and all feedback. This project is open so that I can learn how to be a better developer and hopefully others can learn along with me.

I could not add the README due to character constraints. The file explains the different macros and functions and helps to localize the program to your system, if you choose to actually run it and play with it. You can view the README on the GitHub page.

## dwm-statusbar.h:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libgen.h>

// X11
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

// weather
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <cJSON/cJSON.h>

// wifi
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netlink/genl/genl.h>
#include <netlink/genl/ctrl.h>
#include <linux/nl80211.h>
#include <libnetlink.h>
#include <linux/if_arp.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// disk usage
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

// memory
#include <proc/sysinfo.h>

// volume
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define COLOR_NORMAL                color1
#define COLOR_ACTIVE                color2
#define COLOR1                      color3
#define COLOR2                      color4
#define COLOR_WARNING               color5
#define COLOR_ERROR                 color6
#define GREEN_TEXT                  color7
#define RED_TEXT                    color8
#define COLOR_HEADING               COLOR_ACTIVE

#define TODO_MAX_LEN                100
#define WIFI_INTERFACE              "wlp4s0"
#define DISPLAY_KBD                 true

#define TODO_FILE                   "/home/user/.TODO"
#define STATUSBAR_LOG_FILE          "/home/user/.logs/dwm-statusbar.log"
#define DWM_LOG_FILE                "/home/user/.logs/dwm.log"
#define BACKUP_STATUS_FILE          "/home/user/.backup/.sb"
#define LOCATION                    "0000000"
#define KEY                         "00000000000000000000000000000000"
#define RH_LOGIN                    "username={username}&password={password}

#define DWM_CONFIG_FILE             "/home/user/.dwm/config.h"
#define NET_RX_FILE                 NET_CAT(WIFI_INTERFACE, rx)
#define NET_TX_FILE                 NET_CAT(WIFI_INTERFACE, tx)
#define CPU_USAGE_FILE              "/proc/stat"
#define CPU_TEMP_DIR                "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/"
#define FAN_SPEED_FILE              "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/device/fan1_input"
#define SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_FILE      "/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_backlight/brightness"
#define KBD_BRIGHTNESS_FILE         "/sys/class/leds/smc::kbd_backlight/brightness"
#define BATT_STATUS_FILE            "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status"
#define BATT_CAPACITY_FILE          "/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity"

#define ERR(str, val) \
    { snprintf(str, sizeof(str) - 1, "%c %s%c ", COLOR_ERROR, val, COLOR_NORMAL); \
    str[sizeof(str) - 1] = '\0'; \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\t%s\n\n", asctime(tm_struct), val); \
    return -1; }

#define INIT_ERR(val) \
    { fprintf(stderr, "%s\t%s\n", asctime(tm_struct), val); \
    perror("\tError"); \
    printf("\n"); \
    return -1; }

#define SND_ERR(val) \
    { snd_mixer_close(handle); \
    handle = NULL; \
    snd_config_update_free_global(); \
    snprintf(volume_string, sizeof(volume_string) - 1, "%c %s%c ", COLOR_ERROR, val, COLOR_NORMAL); \
    volume_string[sizeof(volume_string) - 1] = '\0'; \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n\n", asctime(tm_struct), val); \
    return -1; }

#define SND_INIT_ERR(val) \
    { snd_mixer_close(handle); \
    handle = NULL; \
    snd_config_update_free_global(); \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s%s\n", asctime(tm_struct), val); \
    perror("Error"); \
    printf("\n"); \
    return -1; }

#define CAT_5(A, B, C, D, E) #A B #C #D #E
#define NET_CAT(X, Y) CAT_5(/sys/class/net/, X, /statistics/, Y, _bytes)

struct json_struct {
    char *data;
    int size;
};

struct disk_usage_struct {
    struct statvfs fs_stat;
    float bytes_used;
    float bytes_total;
    char unit_used;
    char unit_total;
} root_fs;


struct cpu_temp_list {
    char *filename;
    struct cpu_temp_list *next;
} *temp_list = NULL;

const char color1 = '';
const char color2 = '';
const char color3 = '';
const char color4 = '';
const char color5 = '';
const char color6 = '';
const char color7 = '';
const char color8 = '';

long TODO_mtime = 0;
char weather_url[128];
char forecast_url[128];
int day_safe;               // due to cJSON's not being thread-safe
int temp_today;
bool weather_update = true;
long backup_mtime = 0;
bool equity_found = false;
bool portfolio_init = false;
char portfolio_url[128];
char token_header[64];
char account_number[32];
float equity_previous_close = 0.0;
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
bool wifi_connected = false;
int devidx;
struct tm *tm_struct = NULL;
int block_size;
int cpu_ratio;
int temp_max;
int fan_min;
int fan_max;
int screen_brightness_max;
int kbd_brightness_max;
float vol_range;

char statusbar_string[1024];
char top_bar[512];
char bottom_bar[512];
int bar_max_len;

char TODO_string[128];
char log_status_string[32];
char weather_string[96];
char backup_status_string[32];
char portfolio_value_string[32];
char wifi_status_string[32];
char time_string[32];

char network_usage_string[64];
char disk_usage_string[64];
char memory_string[32];
char cpu_load_string[32];
char cpu_usage_string[32];
char cpu_temp_string[32];
char fan_speed_string[32];

char brightness_string[32];
char volume_string[32];
char battery_string[32];
```

## dwm-statusbar.c:

```
#include "dwm-statusbar.h"

static void
center_bottom_bar(char *bottom_bar)
{
    if (strlen(bottom_bar) < bar_max_len) {
        int half = (bar_max_len - strlen(bottom_bar)) / 2;
        memmove(bottom_bar + half, bottom_bar, strlen(bottom_bar));
        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++)
            bottom_bar[i] = ' ';
    }
}

static int
format_string(Display *dpy, Window root)
{
    memset(statusbar_string, '\0', 1024);
    memset(top_bar, '\0', 512);
    memset(bottom_bar, '\0', 512);

    strcat(top_bar, TODO_string);
    strcat(top_bar, log_status_string);
    strcat(top_bar, weather_string);
    strcat(top_bar, backup_status_string);
    strcat(top_bar, portfolio_value_string);
    strcat(top_bar, wifi_status_string);
    strcat(top_bar, time_string);

    strcat(bottom_bar, network_usage_string);
    strcat(bottom_bar, disk_usage_string);
    strcat(bottom_bar, memory_string);
    strcat(bottom_bar, cpu_load_string);
    strcat(bottom_bar, cpu_usage_string);
    strcat(bottom_bar, cpu_temp_string);
    strcat(bottom_bar, fan_speed_string);

    strcat(bottom_bar, brightness_string);
    strcat(bottom_bar, volume_string);
    strcat(bottom_bar, battery_string);

    center_bottom_bar(bottom_bar);
    sprintf(statusbar_string, "%s;%s", top_bar, bottom_bar);

    if (!XStoreName(dpy, root, statusbar_string))
        return -1;
    if (!XFlush(dpy))
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

static int
get_TODO(void)
{
    // dumb function
    struct stat file_stat;
    if (stat(TODO_FILE, &file_stat) < 0)
        ERR(TODO_string, "Error Getting TODO File Stats")
    if (file_stat.st_mtime <= TODO_mtime)
        return 0;

    TODO_mtime = file_stat.st_mtime;

    FILE *fd;
    char line[128];

    if (!memset(TODO_string, '\0', 128))
        ERR(TODO_string, "Error resetting TODO_string")

    fd = fopen(TODO_FILE, "r");
    if (!fd)
        ERR(TODO_string, "Error Opening TODO File")

    // line 1
    if (fgets(line, 128, fd) == NULL)
        ERR(TODO_string, "All tasks completed!")
    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'; // remove weird characters at end
    snprintf(TODO_string, 128, "%cTODO:%c%s",
            COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL, line);

    // lines 2 and 3
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        memset(line, '\0', 128);
        if (fgets(line, 128, fd) == NULL) break;
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0'; // remove weird characters at end
        switch (line[i]) {
            case '\0': break;
            case '\n': break;
            case '\t':
                memmove(line, line + i + 1, strlen(line));
                strncat(TODO_string, " -> ", sizeof TODO_string - strlen(TODO_string));
                strncat(TODO_string, line, sizeof TODO_string - strlen(TODO_string));
                break;
            default:
                if (i == 1) break;
                strncat(TODO_string, " | ", sizeof TODO_string - strlen(TODO_string));
                strncat(TODO_string, line, sizeof TODO_string - strlen(TODO_string));
                break;
        }
    }

    memset(TODO_string + TODO_MAX_LEN - 3, '.', 3);
    TODO_string[TODO_MAX_LEN] = '\0';

    if (fclose(fd))
        ERR(TODO_string, "Error Closing File")

    return 0;
}

static int
get_log_status(void)
{
    struct stat sb_stat;
    struct stat dwm_stat;

    if (stat(STATUSBAR_LOG_FILE, &sb_stat) < 0)
        ERR(log_status_string, "dwm-statusbar.log error")
    if (stat(DWM_LOG_FILE, &dwm_stat) < 0)
        ERR(log_status_string, "dwm.log error")

    if ((intmax_t)sb_stat.st_size > 1)
        sprintf(log_status_string, "%c Check SB Log%c ",
                COLOR_ERROR, COLOR_NORMAL);
    else if ((intmax_t)dwm_stat.st_size > 1)
        sprintf(log_status_string, "%c Check DWM Log%c ",
                COLOR_ERROR, COLOR_NORMAL);
    else
        if (!memset(log_status_string, '\0', 32))
            ERR(log_status_string, "error resetting log_status_string")

    return 0;
}

static int
get_index(cJSON *time_obj)
{
    const time_t time = time_obj->valueint;
    struct tm *ft_struct = localtime(&time);
    const int ft_day_of_week = ft_struct->tm_wday;
    int day = ft_day_of_week - day_safe;
    if (day < 0)
        day += 7;

    return day;
}

static int
parse_forecast_json(char *raw_json)
{
    // for 5-day forecast (sent as 3-hour intervals for 5 days)
    // only able to handle rain currently

    cJSON *parsed_json = cJSON_Parse(raw_json);
    cJSON *list_array, *list_child;
    cJSON *main_dict, *temp_obj;
    cJSON *rain_dict, *rain_obj;
    int i;
    char forecast_string[32], tmp_str[16];
    if (!memset(forecast_string, '\0', 32))
        return -1;

    struct data {
        int high;
        int low;
        float precipitation;
    } data[5];

    const char days_of_week[10][4] = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed" };

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (!i) {
            data[i].high = temp_today;
            data[i].low = temp_today;
        } else {
            // god help us all if these values don't work
            data[i].high = -1000;
            data[i].low = 1000;
        }
            data[i].precipitation = 0.0;
    }

    list_array = cJSON_GetObjectItem(parsed_json, "list");
    if (!list_array)
        ERR(weather_string, "Error finding 'list' in forecast")
    cJSON_ArrayForEach(list_child, list_array) {
        int f_day = get_index(cJSON_GetObjectItem(list_child, "dt"));
        if (f_day > 3)
            break;

        main_dict = cJSON_GetObjectItem(list_child, "main");
        if (!main_dict)
            ERR(weather_string, "Error finding 'main_dict' in forecast")
        temp_obj = cJSON_GetObjectItem(main_dict, "temp");
        if (!temp_obj)
            ERR(weather_string, "Error finding 'temp_obj' in forecast")
        data[f_day].high = (int)fmax(data[f_day].high, temp_obj->valueint);
        data[f_day].low = (int)fmin(data[f_day].low, temp_obj->valueint);

        if (rain_dict = cJSON_GetObjectItem(list_child, "rain"))
            if (rain_obj = rain_dict->child)
                data[f_day].precipitation += rain_obj->valuedouble;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        snprintf(tmp_str, 16, "%c %s(%2d/%2d)",
                data[i].precipitation >= 3 ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL,
                i > 0 ? days_of_week[day_safe + i - 1] : "",
                data[i].high, data[i].low);
        strncat(weather_string, tmp_str, sizeof weather_string - strlen(weather_string) - 1);
    }

    cJSON_Delete(parsed_json);
    return 0;
}

static int
parse_weather_json(char *raw_json)
{
    // for current weather
    // only able to handle rain currently (winter is not coming)
    // if (id >= 200 && id < 300)
        // Stormy
    // else if (id >= 300 && id < 400)
        // Drizzly
    // else if (id >= 500 && id < 600)
        // Rainy
    // else if (id >= 700 && id < 800)
        // Low visibility
    // else if (id == 800)
        // Clear
    // else if (id > 800 && id < 900)
        // Cloudy

    cJSON *parsed_json = cJSON_Parse(raw_json);
    cJSON *main_dict, *temp_obj;
    cJSON *weather_dict;
    int id;

    main_dict = cJSON_GetObjectItem(parsed_json, "main");
    if (!main_dict)
        ERR(weather_string, "Error finding 'main' in weather")
    temp_obj = cJSON_GetObjectItem(main_dict, "temp");
    if (!temp_obj)
        ERR(weather_string, "Error finding 'temp' in weather")
    temp_today = temp_obj->valueint;

    weather_dict = cJSON_GetObjectItem(parsed_json, "weather");
    if (!weather_dict)
        ERR(weather_string, "Error finding 'weather' in weather")
    weather_dict = weather_dict->child;
    if (!weather_dict)
        ERR(weather_string, "Error finding 'weather' in weather")
    id = cJSON_GetObjectItem(weather_dict, "id")->valueint;
    if (!id)
        ERR(weather_string, "Error getting id from weather")

    snprintf(weather_string, 96, " %c weather:%c%2d F",
            id < 800 ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_HEADING,
            id < 800 ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL,
            temp_today);

    cJSON_Delete(parsed_json);
    return 0;
}

static size_t
curl_callback(char *weather_json, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    const size_t received_size = size * nmemb;
    struct json_struct *tmp;

    tmp = (struct json_struct *)userdata;

    tmp->data = realloc(tmp->data, tmp->size + received_size + 1);
    if (!tmp->data)
        return -1;

    memcpy(&(tmp->data[tmp->size]), weather_json, received_size);
    tmp->size += received_size;
    tmp->data[tmp->size] = '\0';

    return received_size;
}

static int
get_weather(void)
{
    if (!memset(weather_string, '\0', 96))
        ERR(weather_string, "Error resetting weather_string")

    if (wifi_connected == false) {
        sprintf(weather_string, "%c weather:%cN/A ", COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL);
        return -2;
    }

    CURL *curl;
    int i;
    struct json_struct json_structs[2];
    static const char *urls[2] = { weather_url, forecast_url };
    char cap[3];

    day_safe = tm_struct->tm_wday;

    if (curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL))
        ERR(weather_string, "Error curl_global_init(). Please fix issue and restart.")
    if (!(curl = curl_easy_init()))
        ERR(weather_string, "Error curl_easy_init(). Please fix issue and restart.")

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        json_structs[i].data = (char *)malloc(1);
        if (json_structs[i].data == NULL)
            ERR(weather_string, "Out of memory");
        json_structs[i].size = 0;

        if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urls[i]) != CURLE_OK ||
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0") != CURLE_OK ||
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_callback) != CURLE_OK ||
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &json_structs[i]) != CURLE_OK)
            ERR(weather_string, "Error curl_easy_setops() in get_weather(). Please fix issue and restart.")
        if (curl_easy_perform(curl) == CURLE_OK) {
            if (!i) {
                if (parse_weather_json(json_structs[i].data) < 0)
                    ERR(weather_string, "Error parsing weather json. Please fix issue and restart.")
            } else {
                if (parse_forecast_json(json_structs[i].data) < 0)
                    ERR(weather_string, "Error parsing forecast json. Please fix issue and restart.")
            }
            sprintf(cap, "%c ", COLOR_NORMAL);
            strcat(weather_string, cap);
            weather_update = false;
        } else
            sprintf(weather_string, "%c weather:%cN/A ",
                    COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL);
    }

    free(json_structs[0].data);
    free(json_structs[1].data);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}

static int
parse_error_code(int code, char *ret_str)
{
    switch (code) {
        case 20:
            strcpy(ret_str, "already done"); break;
        case 21:
            strcpy(ret_str, "tar error"); break;
        case 22:
            strcpy(ret_str, "gpg error"); break;
        case 23:
            strcpy(ret_str, "no acc token"); break;
        case 24:
            strcpy(ret_str, "error get url"); break;
        case 25:
            strcpy(ret_str, "token timeout"); break;
        case 26:
            strcpy(ret_str, "err verifying"); break;
        default:
            strcpy(ret_str, "err in backup");
    }

    return 0;
}

static int
get_backup_status(void)
{
    struct stat file_stat;
    if (stat(BACKUP_STATUS_FILE, &file_stat) < 0)
        ERR(backup_status_string, "Error Getting Backup File Stats")
    if (file_stat.st_mtime <= backup_mtime)
        return 0;

    backup_mtime = file_stat.st_mtime;

    FILE *fd;
    char line[32], print[16], color = COLOR_ERROR;
    int value;
    time_t curr_time;
    time_t t_diff;

    if (!memset(backup_status_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(backup_status_string, "Error resetting backup_status_string")

    if (!(fd = fopen(BACKUP_STATUS_FILE, "r")))
        ERR(backup_status_string, "Error Opening Backup Status File")

    if (fgets(line, 32, fd) == NULL)
        ERR(backup_status_string, "No Backup History")

    if (fclose(fd))
        ERR(backup_status_string, "Error Closing Backup Status File")

    if (isdigit(line[0])) {
        sscanf(line, "%d", &value);

        if (value >= 20 && value <= 26)
            parse_error_code(value, print);
        else {
            time(&curr_time);
            t_diff = curr_time - value;
            if (t_diff > 86400)
                strcpy(print, "missed");
            else {
                strcpy(print, "done");
                color = COLOR1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
        strcpy(print, line);
        color = COLOR2;
    }

    snprintf(backup_status_string, 32, "%cbackup:%c %s%c ",
            COLOR_HEADING, color, print, COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static double
parse_portfolio_json(char *raw_json)
{
    cJSON *parsed_json = cJSON_Parse(raw_json);
    cJSON *equity_obj, *extended_hours_equity_obj;
    cJSON *equity_previous_close_obj;
    double equity_f;

    equity_obj = cJSON_GetObjectItem(parsed_json, "equity");
    if (!equity_obj)
        return -1;

    extended_hours_equity_obj = cJSON_GetObjectItem(parsed_json, "extended_hours_equity");
    if (!extended_hours_equity_obj)
        return -1;

    if (extended_hours_equity_obj->valuestring == NULL)
        equity_f = atof(equity_obj->valuestring);
    else
        equity_f = atof(extended_hours_equity_obj->valuestring);

    if (!equity_previous_close) {
        equity_previous_close_obj = cJSON_GetObjectItem(parsed_json, "equity_previous_close");
        if (!equity_previous_close_obj)
            return -1;
        equity_previous_close = atof(equity_previous_close_obj->valuestring);
    }

    cJSON_Delete(parsed_json);
    return equity_f;
}

static int
get_portfolio_value(void)
{
    // Robinhood starts trading at 9:00 am EST
    if (timezone / 3600 + tm_struct->tm_hour < 14 && equity_found == true)
        return 0;
    // Robinhood stops after-market trading at 6:00 pm EST
    if (timezone / 3600 + tm_struct->tm_hour > 23 && equity_found == true)
        return 0;

    if (wifi_connected == false) {
        sprintf(portfolio_value_string, "%crobinhood:%cN/A",
                COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL);
        return -2;
    }

    if (portfolio_init == false)
        return -2;

    if (!memset(portfolio_value_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(portfolio_value_string, "Error resetting portfolio_va...")

    int tz_gap;
    CURL *curl;
    struct json_struct portfolio_jstruct;
    static double equity;

    portfolio_jstruct.data = (char *)malloc(1);
    if (portfolio_jstruct.data == NULL)
        ERR(portfolio_value_string, "Out of memory");
    portfolio_jstruct.size = 0;

    if (curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL))
        ERR(portfolio_value_string, "Error curl_global_init()")
    if (!(curl = curl_easy_init()))
        ERR(portfolio_value_string, "Error curl_easy_init()")

    if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, portfolio_url) != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers) != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0") != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_callback) != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &portfolio_jstruct) != CURLE_OK)
        ERR(portfolio_value_string, "Error curl_easy_setops()")
    if (curl_easy_perform(curl) == CURLE_OK) {
        if ((equity = parse_portfolio_json(portfolio_jstruct.data)) < 0)
            ERR(portfolio_value_string, "Error parsing portfolio json")

        sprintf(portfolio_value_string, "%crobinhood:%c%.2lf",
                COLOR_HEADING, equity >= equity_previous_close ? GREEN_TEXT : RED_TEXT, equity);
        equity_found = true;
    } else
        sprintf(portfolio_value_string, "%crobinhood:%cN/A",
                COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL);

    free(portfolio_jstruct.data);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}

static int
free_wifi_list(struct nlmsg_list *list)
{
    struct nlmsg_list *next;

    while (list != NULL) {
        next = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
}

static int
format_wifi_status(char color)
{
    char tmp[32];

    if (strlen(wifi_status_string) > (sizeof wifi_status_string - 6))
        memset(wifi_status_string + strlen(wifi_status_string) - 3, '.', 3);

    sprintf(tmp, " %cwifi:%c %s %c ",
            COLOR_HEADING, color, wifi_status_string, COLOR_NORMAL);
    strcpy(wifi_status_string, tmp);

    return 0;
}

static int
print_ssid(uint8_t len, uint8_t *data)
{
    // stolen from iw
    int i;
    uint8_t tmp_str[2];

    memset(wifi_status_string, '\0', 32);
    for (i = 0; i < len && i < sizeof wifi_status_string; i++) {
        if (isprint(data[i]) && data[i] != ' ' && data[i] != '\\')
            sprintf(tmp_str, "%c", data[i]);
        else if (data[i] == ' ' && (i != 0 && i != len -1))
            sprintf(tmp_str, " ");
        else
            sprintf(tmp_str, "\\x%.2x", data[i]);
        strncat(wifi_status_string, tmp_str,
                sizeof wifi_status_string - strlen(wifi_status_string) - 1);
    }

    return 0;
}

static int
wifi_callback(struct nl_msg *msg, void *arg)
{
    struct nlattr *tb[NL80211_ATTR_MAX + 1];
    struct genlmsghdr *gnlh = nlmsg_data(nlmsg_hdr(msg));
    uint8_t len;
    uint8_t *data;

    nla_parse(tb, NL80211_ATTR_MAX, genlmsg_attrdata(gnlh, 0),
          genlmsg_attrlen(gnlh, 0), NULL);

    if (tb[NL80211_ATTR_SSID]) {
        len = nla_len(tb[NL80211_ATTR_SSID]);
        data = nla_data(tb[NL80211_ATTR_SSID]);
        print_ssid(len, data);
    }

    return NL_SKIP;
}

static int
store_nlmsg(const struct sockaddr_nl *who, struct nlmsghdr *hdr, void *arg)
{
    // stolen from iproute2
    struct nlmsg_list **linfo = (struct nlmsg_list**)arg;

    for (linfo; *linfo; linfo = &(*linfo)->next);
    *linfo = (struct nlmsg_list *)malloc(hdr->nlmsg_len + sizeof(void*));
    if (*linfo == NULL)
        return -1;

    memcpy(&(*linfo)->h, hdr, hdr->nlmsg_len);
    (*linfo)->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}

static int
ip_check(int flag)
{
    // stolen from iproute2
    struct rtnl_handle rth;
    struct nlmsg_list *linfo = NULL;
    struct nlmsg_list *head = NULL;

    struct ifinfomsg *ifi;
    struct rtattr *tb[IFLA_MAX+1];
    int len;
    int rv;

    if (rtnl_open(&rth, 0) < 0)
        ERR(wifi_status_string, "error: rtnl_open")
    if (rtnl_wilddump_request(&rth, AF_PACKET, RTM_GETLINK) < 0)
        ERR(wifi_status_string, "error: rtnl_wilddump_request")
    if (rtnl_dump_filter(&rth, store_nlmsg, &linfo) < 0)
        ERR(wifi_status_string, "error: rtnl_dump_filter")
    rtnl_close(&rth);

    head = linfo;
    for (int i = 1; i < devidx; i++, linfo = linfo->next);
    ifi = NLMSG_DATA(&linfo->h);
    if (!ifi)
        ERR(wifi_status_string, "error accessing ifi")

    len = linfo->h.nlmsg_len - NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(*ifi));
    parse_rtattr(tb, IFLA_MAX, IFLA_RTA(ifi), len);

    if (flag)
        // 2 if down, 6 if up
        rv = *(__u8 *)RTA_DATA(tb[IFLA_OPERSTATE]);
    else
        // 0 if down, 1 if up
        rv = ifi->ifi_flags & IFF_UP;

    free_wifi_list(head);
    return rv;
}

static int
get_wifi_status(void)
{
    struct nl_sock *socket;
    int id;
    struct nl_msg *msg;
    struct nl_cb *cb;

    int ifi_flag;
    int op_state;
    char color = COLOR2;

    ifi_flag = ip_check(0);
    if (ifi_flag == -1) return -1;
    op_state = ip_check(1);
    if (op_state == -1) return -1;

    if (ifi_flag == 0 && op_state == 2) {
        strncpy(wifi_status_string, "Wireless Device Set Down", 31);
        wifi_connected = false;
    } else if (ifi_flag && op_state == 0) {
        strncpy(wifi_status_string, "Wireless State Unknown", 31);
        wifi_connected = false;
    } else if (ifi_flag && op_state == 2) {
        strncpy(wifi_status_string, "No Connection Initiated", 31);
        wifi_connected = false;
    } else if (ifi_flag && op_state == 5) {
        strncpy(wifi_status_string, "No Carrier", 31);
        wifi_connected = false;
    } else if (ifi_flag && op_state == 6) {
        if (wifi_connected == true) return 0;
        if (!memset(wifi_status_string, '\0', 32))
            ERR(wifi_status_string, "Error resetting wifi_status_string")

        socket = nl_socket_alloc();
        if (!socket)
            ERR(wifi_status_string, "err: nl_socket_alloc()")
        if (genl_connect(socket) < 0)
            ERR(wifi_status_string, "err: genl_connect()")
        id = genl_ctrl_resolve(socket, "nl80211");
        if (!id)
            ERR(wifi_status_string, "err: genl_ctrl_resolve()")

        msg = nlmsg_alloc();
        if (!msg)
            ERR(wifi_status_string, "err: nlmsg_alloc()")
        cb = nl_cb_alloc(NL_CB_DEFAULT);
        if (!cb)
            ERR(wifi_status_string, "err: nl_cb_alloc()")

        genlmsg_put(msg, 0, 0, id, 0, 0, NL80211_CMD_GET_INTERFACE, 0);
        if (nla_put(msg, NL80211_ATTR_IFINDEX, sizeof(uint32_t), &devidx) < 0)
            ERR(wifi_status_string, "err: nla_put()")
        nl_send_auto_complete(socket, msg);
        if (nl_cb_set(cb, NL_CB_VALID, NL_CB_CUSTOM, wifi_callback, NULL) < 0)
            ERR(wifi_status_string, "err: nla_cb_set()")
        if (nl_recvmsgs(socket, cb) < 0)
            strncpy(wifi_status_string, "No Wireless Connection", 31);
        else
            color = COLOR1;

        wifi_connected = true;
        nlmsg_free(msg);
        nl_socket_free(socket);
        free(cb);
    } else
        ERR(wifi_status_string, "Error with WiFi Status")

    format_wifi_status(color);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_time(void)
{
    if (!memset(time_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(time_string, "Error resetting time_string")

    if (strftime(time_string, 32,  "%b %d - %I:%M", tm_struct) == 0)
        ERR(time_string, "Error with strftime()")
    if (tm_struct->tm_sec % 2)
        time_string[strlen(time_string) - 3] = ' ';

    return 0;
}

static char
get_unit(int unit)
{
    switch (unit) {
        case 1: return 'K';
        case 2: return 'M';
        case 3: return 'G';
        default: return 'B';
    }
}

static int
format_bytes(long *bytes, int *step)
{
    long bytes_n = *bytes;
    int step_n = 0;

    while (bytes_n >= 1 << 10) {
        bytes_n = bytes_n >> 10;
        step_n++;
    }

    *bytes = bytes_n;
    *step = step_n;

    return 0;
}

static int
get_network_usage(void)
{
    if (!memset(network_usage_string, '\0', 64))
        ERR(network_usage_string, "Error resetting network_usage")

    /* from top.c */
    const char* files[2] = { NET_RX_FILE, NET_TX_FILE };
    FILE *fd;
    char line[64];
    static long rx_old, tx_old;
    long rx_new, tx_new;
    long rx_bps, tx_bps;
    int step = 0;
    char rx_unit, tx_unit;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        fd = fopen(files[i], "r");
        if (!fd)
            ERR(network_usage_string, "Read Error")
        fgets(line, 64, fd);
        if (fclose(fd))
            ERR(network_usage_string, "Close Error")

        if (i) {
            sscanf(line, "%d", &tx_new);
            tx_bps = tx_new - tx_old;
            format_bytes(&tx_bps, &step);
            tx_unit = get_unit(step);
        } else {
            sscanf(line, "%d", &rx_new);
            rx_bps = rx_new - rx_old;
            format_bytes(&rx_bps, &step);
            rx_unit = get_unit(step);
        }
    }

    if (rx_bps > 999) rx_bps = 999;
    if (tx_bps > 999) tx_bps = 999;

    snprintf(network_usage_string, 64, "%cnetwork:%c%3d %c/S down,%c%3d %c/S up%c ",
            COLOR_HEADING, rx_unit == 'M' ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL, rx_bps, rx_unit,
            tx_unit == 'M' ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL, tx_bps, tx_unit, COLOR_NORMAL);

    rx_old = rx_new;
    tx_old = tx_new;

    return 0;
}

static int
process_stat(struct disk_usage_struct *dus)
{
    int unit_int = 0;
    float bytes_used;
    float bytes_total;

    bytes_used = (float)(dus->fs_stat.f_blocks - dus->fs_stat.f_bfree) * block_size;
    bytes_total = (float)dus->fs_stat.f_blocks *  block_size;

    while (bytes_used > 1 << 10) {
        bytes_used /= 1024;
        unit_int++;
    }
    dus->bytes_used = bytes_used;
    dus->unit_used = get_unit(unit_int);

    unit_int = 0;
    while (bytes_total > 1 << 10) {
        bytes_total /= 1024;
        unit_int++;
    }
    dus->bytes_total = bytes_total;
    dus->unit_total = get_unit(unit_int);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_disk_usage(void)
{
    if (!memset(disk_usage_string, '\0', 64))
        ERR(disk_usage_string, "Error resetting disk_usage_string")

    int rootperc;

    if (statvfs("/", &root_fs.fs_stat) < 0)
        ERR(disk_usage_string, "Error getting filesystem stats")

    process_stat(&root_fs);
    rootperc = rint((double)root_fs.bytes_used / (double)root_fs.bytes_total * 100);

    snprintf(disk_usage_string, 64, " %c disk:%c%.1f%c/%.1f%c%c ", 
            rootperc >= 75? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_HEADING,
            rootperc >= 75? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL,
            root_fs.bytes_used, root_fs.unit_used, root_fs.bytes_total, root_fs.unit_total,
            COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_memory(void)
{
    if (!memset(memory_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(memory_string, "Error resetting memory_string")

    int memperc;

    meminfo();

    memperc = rint((double)kb_active / (double)kb_main_total * 100);
    if (memperc > 99)
        memperc = 99;

    snprintf(memory_string, 32, " %c RAM:%c%2d%% used%c ",
            memperc >= 75? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_HEADING,
            memperc >= 75? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL,
            memperc, COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_cpu_load(void)
{
    if (!memset(cpu_load_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(cpu_load_string, "Error resetting cpu_load_string")

    // why was this static?
    double av[3];

    loadavg(&av[0], &av[1], &av[2]);
    snprintf(cpu_load_string, 32, " %c load:%c%.2f %.2f %.2f%c ",
            av[0] > 1 ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_HEADING,
            av[0] > 1 ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL,
            av[0], av[1], av[2], COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_cpu_usage(void)
{
    if (!memset(cpu_usage_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(cpu_usage_string, "Error resetting cpu_usage_string")

    /* from top.c */
    FILE *fd;
    char buf[64];
    int seca = 0, secb = 0, secc = 0, secd = 0, top, bottom, total = 0;
    int i;

    static struct {
        int oldval[4];
        int newval[4];
    } cpu;

    fd = fopen(CPU_USAGE_FILE, "r");
    if (!fd)
        ERR(cpu_usage_string, "Read Error")
    fgets(buf, 64, fd);
    if (fclose(fd))
        ERR(cpu_usage_string, "Close Error")

    sscanf(buf, "cpu %d %d %d %d", &cpu.newval[0], &cpu.newval[1], &cpu.newval[2], &cpu.newval[3]);

    // exclude first run
    if (cpu.oldval[0]) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            secc += cpu.newval[i];
            secd += cpu.oldval[i];

            if (i == 3) continue;
            seca += cpu.newval[i];
            secb += cpu.oldval[i];
        }

        top = seca - secb + 1;
        bottom = secc - secd + 1;

        total = rint((double)top / (double)bottom * 100);
        total *= cpu_ratio;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cpu.oldval[i] = cpu.newval[i];

    if (total >= 100) total = 99;
    snprintf(cpu_usage_string, 32, " %c CPU usage:%c%2d%%%c ",
            total >= 75 ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_HEADING,
            total >= 75 ? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL,
            total, COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_cpu_temp(void)
{
    if (!memset(cpu_temp_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(cpu_temp_string, "Error resetting cpu_temp_string")

    struct cpu_temp_list *snake;
    int counter;
    int temp = 0;
    int tempperc;

    for (snake = temp_list, counter = 0; snake != NULL; snake = snake->next, counter++) {
        char path[128];
        FILE *fd;
        int tmp;

        strcpy(path, CPU_TEMP_DIR);
        strcat(path, snake->filename);

        fd = fopen(path, "r");
        if (!fd)
            ERR(cpu_temp_string, "Error Opening CPU File")
        if (!fscanf(fd, "%d", &tmp))
            ERR(cpu_temp_string, "Error Scanning CPU File")
        if (fclose(fd))
            ERR(cpu_temp_string, "Error Closing CPU File")
        temp += tmp;
    }

    temp /= counter;
    tempperc = rint((double)temp / (double)temp_max * 100);
    temp >>= 10;

    snprintf(cpu_temp_string, 32, " %c CPU temp:%c%2d degC%c ",
            tempperc >= 75? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_HEADING,
            tempperc >= 75? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL,
            temp, COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_fan_speed(void)
{
    if (!memset(fan_speed_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(fan_speed_string, "Error resetting fan_speed_string")

    FILE *fd;
    int rpm;
    int fanperc;

    fd = fopen(FAN_SPEED_FILE, "r");
    if (!fd)
        ERR(fan_speed_string, "Error Opening File")
    if (!fscanf(fd, "%d", &rpm))
        ERR(fan_speed_string, "Error Scanning File")
    if (fclose(fd))
        ERR(fan_speed_string, "Error Closing File")

    rpm -= fan_min;
    if (rpm <= 0)
        rpm = 0;

    fanperc = rint((double)rpm / (double)fan_max * 100);

    if (fanperc >= 100)
        snprintf(fan_speed_string, 32, " %c fan: MAX%c ", COLOR_WARNING, COLOR_NORMAL);
    else
        snprintf(fan_speed_string, 32, " %c fan:%c%2d%%%c ",
                fanperc >= 75? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_HEADING,
                fanperc >= 75? COLOR_WARNING : COLOR_NORMAL,
                fanperc, COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_brightness(void)
{
    if (!memset(brightness_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(brightness_string, "Error resetting brightness_string")

    const char* b_files[2] = { SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_FILE, KBD_BRIGHTNESS_FILE };

    int scrn, kbd;
    int scrn_perc, kbd_perc;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (i == 1 && DISPLAY_KBD == false) continue;
        FILE *fd;
        fd = fopen(b_files[i], "r");
        if (!fd)
            ERR(brightness_string, "Error w File Open")
        fscanf(fd, "%d", i == 0 ? &scrn : &kbd);
        if (fclose(fd))
            ERR(brightness_string, "Error File Close")
    }

    scrn_perc = rint((double)scrn / (double)screen_brightness_max * 100);
    if (DISPLAY_KBD == true)
        kbd_perc = rint((double)kbd / (double)kbd_brightness_max * 100);

    if (DISPLAY_KBD == true)
        snprintf(brightness_string, 32, " %c brightness:%c%3d%%, %3d%%%c ",
            COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL, scrn_perc, kbd_perc, COLOR_NORMAL);
    else
        snprintf(brightness_string, 32, " %c brightness:%c%3d%%%c ",
            COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL, scrn_perc, COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_volume(void)
{
    if (!memset(volume_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(volume_string, "Error resetting volume_string")

    // stolen from amixer utility from alsa-utils
    long pvol;
    int swch, volperc;

    snd_mixer_t *handle = NULL;
    snd_mixer_elem_t *elem;
    snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;

    if (snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0))
        SND_ERR("Error Open")
    if (snd_mixer_attach(handle, "default"))
        SND_ERR("Error Attch")
    if (snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL))
        SND_ERR("Error Rgstr")
    if (snd_mixer_load(handle))
        SND_ERR("Error Load")

    snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
    snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, "Master");

    if (!(elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle, sid)))
        SND_ERR("Error Elem")

    if (snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_switch(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_MONO, &swch))
        SND_ERR("Error Get S")
    if (!swch) {
        snprintf(volume_string, 32, " %c volume:%cmute%c ",
                COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL, COLOR_NORMAL);
    } else {
        if (snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume(elem, SND_MIXER_SCHN_MONO, &pvol))
            SND_ERR("Error Get V")
        // round to the nearest ten
        volperc = (double)pvol / vol_range * 100;
        volperc = rint((float)volperc / 10) * 10;

        snprintf(volume_string, 32, " %c volume:%c%3d%%%c ",
                COLOR_HEADING, COLOR_NORMAL, volperc, COLOR_NORMAL);
    }

    if (snd_mixer_close(handle))
        SND_ERR("Error Close")
    handle = NULL;
    snd_config_update_free_global();

    return 0;
}

static int
get_battery(void)
{
    if (!memset(battery_string, '\0', 32))
        ERR(battery_string, "Error resetting battery_string")
    /* from acpi.c and other acpi source files */
    FILE *fd;
    char status_string[20];
    int status; // -1 = discharging, 0 = full, 1 = charging
    int capacity;

    const char *filepaths[2] = { BATT_STATUS_FILE, BATT_CAPACITY_FILE };

    fd = fopen(BATT_STATUS_FILE, "r");
    if (!fd)
        ERR(battery_string, "Err Open Bat Fil")
    fscanf(fd, "%s", &status_string);
    if (fclose(fd))
        ERR(battery_string, "Err Close Bat fd")

    if (!strcmp(status_string, "Full") || !strcmp(status_string, "Unknown")) {
        status = 0;
        snprintf(battery_string, 32, " %c battery:%c full %c",
                COLOR_HEADING, COLOR1, COLOR_NORMAL);
        return 0;
    }

    if (!strcmp(status_string, "Discharging"))
        status = -1;
    else if (!strcmp(status_string, "Charging"))
        status = 1;
    else
        ERR(battery_string, "Err Read Bat Sts")

    fd = fopen(BATT_CAPACITY_FILE, "r");
    if (!fd)
        ERR(battery_string, "Err Open Bat Fil")
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &capacity);
    if (fclose(fd))
        ERR(battery_string, "Err Close Bat fd")

    if (capacity > 99)
        capacity = 99;

    snprintf(battery_string, 32, " %c battery: %c%2d%% %c",
            capacity < 20 ? COLOR_ERROR : status > 0 ? COLOR2 : COLOR_WARNING,
            status > 0 ? '+' : '-', capacity, COLOR_NORMAL);

    return 0;
}

static int
parse_account_number_json(char *raw_json)
{
    cJSON *parsed_json = cJSON_Parse(raw_json);
    cJSON *results, *account, *account_num;
    cJSON *weather_dict;
    int id;

    results = cJSON_GetObjectItem(parsed_json, "results");
    if (!results)
        return -1;
    account = results->child;
    if (!account)
        return -1;
    account_num = cJSON_GetObjectItem(account, "account_number");
    if (!account_num)
        return -1;

    strncpy(account_number, account_num->valuestring, 31);

    cJSON_Delete(parsed_json);
    return 0;
}

static int
get_account_number(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    struct json_struct account_number_struct;

    account_number_struct.data = (char *)malloc(1);
    if (account_number_struct.data == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error allocating account_number_struct.data")
    account_number_struct.size = 0;

    if (curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL))
        INIT_ERR("error curl_global_init() in get_account_number()")
    if (!(curl = curl_easy_init()))
        INIT_ERR("error curl_easy_init() in get_account_number()")

    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, token_header);
    if (headers == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error curl_slist_append() in get_account_number()")

    if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.robinhood.com/accounts/") != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers) != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0") != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_callback) != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &account_number_struct) != CURLE_OK)
        INIT_ERR("error curl_easy_setopt() in get_account_number()")
    if (curl_easy_perform(curl) != CURLE_OK)
        INIT_ERR("error curl_easy_perform() in get_account_number()")

    if (parse_account_number_json(account_number_struct.data) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error parse_account_number_json() in get_account_number()")

    free(account_number_struct.data);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}

static int
parse_token_json(char *raw_json)
{
    cJSON *parsed_json = cJSON_Parse(raw_json);
    cJSON *token = cJSON_GetObjectItem(parsed_json, "token");
    if (!token)
        INIT_ERR("error finding \"token\" in token json")

    snprintf(token_header, 64, "Authorization: Token %s", token->valuestring);

    cJSON_Delete(parsed_json);
    return 0;
}

static int
get_token(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    struct json_struct token_struct;
    struct curl_slist *header = NULL;

    token_struct.data = (char *)malloc(1);
    if (token_struct.data == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error allocating token_struct.data")
    token_struct.size = 0;

    if (curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL))
        INIT_ERR("error curl_global_init() in get_token()")
    if (!(curl = curl_easy_init()))
        INIT_ERR("error curl_easy_init() in get_token()")

    header = curl_slist_append(header, "Accept: application/json");
    if (header == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error curl_slist_append() in get_token()")

    if (curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.robinhood.com/api-token-auth/") != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header) != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, RH_LOGIN) != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0") != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_callback) != CURLE_OK ||
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &token_struct) != CURLE_OK)
        INIT_ERR("error curl_easy_setopt() in get_token()")
    if (curl_easy_perform(curl) != CURLE_OK)
        INIT_ERR("error curl_easy_perform() in get_token()")

    if (parse_token_json(token_struct.data) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error parse_token_json() in get_token()")

    free(token_struct.data);
    curl_slist_free_all(header);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}

static int
init_portfolio()
{
    if (get_token() < 0)
        return -1;
    if (get_account_number() < 0)
        return -1;
    snprintf(portfolio_url, 128, "https://api.robinhood.com/accounts/%s/portfolio/", account_number);
    portfolio_init = true;

    return 0;
}

static int
populate_tm_struct(void)
{
    time_t tval;
    time(&tval);
    tm_struct = localtime(&tval);

    return 0;
}

static int
loop (Display *dpy, Window root)
{
    int weather_return = 0;

    while (1) {
        // get times
        populate_tm_struct();

        // // run every second
        get_time();
        get_network_usage();
        get_cpu_usage();
        if (weather_update == true && wifi_connected == true)
            if ((weather_return = get_weather()) < 0)
                if (weather_return != -2)
                    break;
        if (portfolio_init == false && wifi_connected == true)
            init_portfolio();

        // run every five seconds
        if (tm_struct->tm_sec % 5 == 0) {
            get_TODO();
            get_backup_status();
            if (get_portfolio_value() == -1)
                break;
            if (get_wifi_status() < 0)
                break;
            get_memory();
            get_cpu_load();
            get_cpu_temp();
            get_fan_speed();
            get_brightness();
            get_volume();
            get_battery();
        }

        // run every minute
        if (tm_struct->tm_sec == 0) {
            get_log_status();
            get_disk_usage();
        }

        // run every 3 hours
        if ((tm_struct->tm_hour + 1) % 3 == 0 && tm_struct->tm_min == 0 && tm_struct->tm_sec == 0)
            if (wifi_connected == false)
                weather_update = true;
            else
                if ((weather_return = get_weather()) < 0)
                    if (weather_return != -2)
                        break;

        format_string(dpy, root);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return -1;
}

static int
make_urls(void)
{
    snprintf(weather_url, 128, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=%s&appid=%s&units=imperial", LOCATION, KEY);
    snprintf(forecast_url, 128, "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=%s&appid=%s&units=imperial", LOCATION, KEY);

    return 0;
}

static int
get_vol_range(void)
{
    long min, max;

    snd_mixer_t *handle = NULL;
    snd_mixer_elem_t *elem;
    snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;

    // stolen from amixer utility from alsa-utils
    if ((snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0)) < 0)
        SND_INIT_ERR("error opening volume handle")
    if ((snd_mixer_attach(handle, "default")) < 0)
        SND_INIT_ERR("error attaching volume handle")
    if ((snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
        SND_INIT_ERR("error registering volume handle")
    if ((snd_mixer_load(handle)) < 0)
        SND_INIT_ERR("error loading volume handle")

    snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
    if (sid == NULL)
        SND_INIT_ERR("error allocating memory for volume id")

    snd_mixer_selem_id_set_name(sid, "Master");
    if (!(elem = snd_mixer_find_selem(handle, sid)))
        SND_INIT_ERR("error finding volume property")

    if (snd_mixer_selem_get_playback_volume_range(elem, &min, &max))
        SND_INIT_ERR("error getting volume range")

    if (snd_mixer_close(handle))
        SND_INIT_ERR("error closing volume handle")
    handle = NULL;
    snd_config_update_free_global();

    return max - min;
}

static int
get_kbd_brightness_max(void)
{
    char file_str[128];
    char dir_str[128];
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    int count = 0;
    FILE *fd;
    int max;

    strcpy(file_str, KBD_BRIGHTNESS_FILE);
    strcpy(dir_str, dirname(file_str));

    if ((dir = opendir(dir_str)) == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error opening keyboard brightness directory")

    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        if (!strcmp(file->d_name, "max_brightness")) {
            if (strlen(dir_str) + strlen(file->d_name) + 2 > sizeof dir_str)
                break;
            strcat(dir_str, "/");
            strcat(dir_str, file->d_name);
            count++;
            break;
        }
    if (!count)
        INIT_ERR("error finding keyboard brightness directory")

    fd = fopen(dir_str, "r");
    if (!fd)
        INIT_ERR("error opening keyboard brightness file")
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &max);

    if (fclose(fd) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing keyboard brightness file")
    if (closedir(dir) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing keyboard brightness directory")
    return max;
}

static int
get_screen_brightness_max(void)
{
    char file_str[128];
    char dir_str[128];
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    int count = 0;
    FILE *fd;
    int max;

    strcpy(file_str, SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_FILE);
    strcpy(dir_str, dirname(file_str));

    if ((dir = opendir(dir_str)) == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error opening screen brightness directory")

    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        if (!strcmp(file->d_name, "max_brightness")) {
            if (strlen(dir_str) + strlen(file->d_name) + 2 > sizeof dir_str)
                break;
            strcat(dir_str, "/");
            strcat(dir_str, file->d_name);
            count++;
            break;
        }
    if (!count)
        INIT_ERR("error finding screen brightness directory")

    fd = fopen(dir_str, "r");
    if (!fd)
        INIT_ERR("error opening screen brightness file")
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &max);

    if (fclose(fd) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing screen brightness file")
    if (closedir(dir) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing screen brightness directory")
    return max;
}

static int
get_fan_max(void)
{
    char file_str[128];
    char dir_str[128];
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    char tmp[64];
    char *token;
    FILE *fd;
    int count = 0;
    int max;

    strcpy(file_str, FAN_SPEED_FILE);
    strcpy(dir_str, dirname(file_str));

    if ((dir = opendir(dir_str)) == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error opening fan directory")

    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        strcpy(tmp, file->d_name);
        if ((token = strtok(tmp, "_")))
            if ((token = strtok(NULL, "_")))
                if (!strcmp(token, "max")) {
                    if (strlen(dir_str) + strlen(file->d_name) + 2 > sizeof dir_str)
                        break;
                    strcat(dir_str, "/");
                    strcat(dir_str, file->d_name);
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
    }
    if (!count)
        INIT_ERR("error finding fan max file")

    fd = fopen(dir_str, "r");
    if (!fd)
        INIT_ERR("error opening file in get_fan_max")
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &max);
    max -= fan_min;

    if (fclose(fd) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing file in get_fan_max")
    if (closedir(dir) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing directory in get_fan_max")
    return max;
}

static int
get_fan_min(void)
{
    char file_str[128];
    char dir_str[128];
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    char tmp[64];
    char *token;
    FILE *fd;
    int count = 0;
    int min;

    strcpy(file_str, FAN_SPEED_FILE);
    strcpy(dir_str, dirname(file_str));

    if ((dir = opendir(dir_str)) == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error opening fan directory")

    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        strcpy(tmp, file->d_name);
        if ((token = strtok(tmp, "_")))
            if ((token = strtok(NULL, "_")))
                if (!strcmp(token, "min")) {
                    if (strlen(dir_str) + strlen(file->d_name) + 2 > sizeof(dir_str))
                        break;
                    strcat(dir_str, "/");
                    strcat(dir_str, file->d_name);
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
    }
    if (!count)
        INIT_ERR("error finding fan min file")

    fd = fopen(dir_str, "r");
    if (!fd)
        INIT_ERR("error opening file in get_fan_min")
    fscanf(fd, "%d", &min);

    if (fclose(fd) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing file in get_fan_min")
    if (closedir(dir) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing directory in get_fan_min")
    return min;
}

static int
free_list(struct cpu_temp_list *list)
{
    struct cpu_temp_list *next;

    while (list != NULL) {
        next = list->next;
        free(list->filename);
        free(list);
        list = next;
    }
}

static struct cpu_temp_list *
add_link(struct cpu_temp_list *list, char *filename)
{
    struct cpu_temp_list *new;
    struct cpu_temp_list *worm;

    new = (struct cpu_temp_list *)malloc(sizeof(struct cpu_temp_list));
    if (new == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%serror allocating memory for cpu temperature file list\n",
                asctime(tm_struct));
        perror("Error");
        printf("\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    new->filename = (char *)malloc(strlen(filename) + 1);
    if (new->filename == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%serror allocating memory for cpu temperature file list name\n",
                asctime(tm_struct));
        perror("Error");
        printf("\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(new->filename, filename);
    new->next = NULL;

    if (list == NULL)
        return new;
    else {
        for (worm = list; worm->next != NULL; worm = worm->next);
        worm->next = new;
    }

    return list;
}

static struct cpu_temp_list *
populate_temp_list(struct cpu_temp_list *list, char *match)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *file;
    char tmp[64];
    char *token;
    int count = 0;

    if ((dir = opendir(CPU_TEMP_DIR)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        strcpy(tmp, file->d_name);
        if ((token = strtok(tmp, "_")))
            if ((token = strtok(NULL, "_")))
                if (!strcmp(token, match)) {
                    list = add_link(list, file->d_name);
                    if (list == NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "%serror adding link to cpu temperature file list\n",
                                asctime(tm_struct));
                        perror("Error");
                        printf("\n");
                        return NULL;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
    }
    if (!count) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%serror finding files for cpu temp list\n",
                asctime(tm_struct));
        perror("Error");
        printf("\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (closedir(dir) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%serror closing directory in populate_temp_list\n",
                asctime(tm_struct));
        perror("Error");
        printf("\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return list;
}

static int
get_temp_max(void)
{
    struct cpu_temp_list *max_list = NULL, *snake;
    FILE *fd;
    int max;
    int total = 0;
    int counter;

    max_list = populate_temp_list(max_list, "max");
    if (max_list == NULL)
            INIT_ERR("error populating temperature file list in get_temp_max")

    for (snake = max_list, counter = 0; snake != NULL; snake = snake->next, counter++) {
        char path[128];
        strcpy(path, CPU_TEMP_DIR);
        strcat(path, snake->filename);

        if (!(fd = fopen(path, "r")))
            INIT_ERR("error opening file in get_temp_max")
        if (!fscanf(fd, "%d", &max))
            INIT_ERR("error reading value in get_temp_max")
        if (fclose(fd) < 0)
            INIT_ERR("error closing file in get_temp_max")
        total += max;
    }

    free_list(max_list);
    return total / counter;
}

static int
get_cpu_ratio(void)
{
    FILE *fd;
    char line[256];
    char *token;
    int cores;
    int threads;

    fd = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo", "r");
    if (!fd)
        INIT_ERR("error opening file in get_cpu_ratio")
    while (fgets(line, 256, fd) != NULL && strncmp(line, "cpu cores", 9));
    if (fclose(fd) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing file in get_cpu_ratio")

    token = strtok(line, ":");
    if (token == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error parsing /proc/cpuinfo to get cpu ratio")
    token = strtok(NULL, ":");
    if (token == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error parsing /proc/cpuinfo to get cpu ratio")

    cores = atoi(token);
    if ((threads = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error getting threads in get_cpu_ratio")

    return threads / cores;
}

static int
get_font(char *font)
{
    FILE *fd;
    char line[256];
    char *token;

    if (!(fd = fopen(DWM_CONFIG_FILE, "r")))
        INIT_ERR("error opening file in get_font")
    while (fgets(line, 128, fd) != NULL && strncmp(line, "static const char font[]", 24));
    if (line == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("no font found in config file")
    if (fclose(fd) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error closing file in get_font")

    token = strtok(line, "=");
    if (token == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error parsing dwm config to get font")
    token = strtok(NULL, "=");
    if (token == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error parsing dwm config to get font")

    while (*token != '"') token++;
    token++;
    token = strtok(token, "\"");
    if (token == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error parsing dwm config to get font")

    memcpy(font, token, strlen(token));

    return 0;
}

static int
get_bar_max_len(Display *dpy)
{
    int width_p, width_c;
    char *fontname;
    char **miss_list, *def;
    int count;
    XFontSet fontset;
    XFontStruct *xfont;
    XRectangle rect;

    width_p = DisplayWidth(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy));
    fontname = (char *)malloc(256);
    if (fontname == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error allocating memory for fontname")
    if (get_font(fontname) < 0)
        return -1;
    fontset = XCreateFontSet(dpy, fontname, &miss_list, &count, &def);
    if (fontset) {
        width_c = XmbTextExtents(fontset, "0", 1, NULL, &rect);
        XFreeFontSet(dpy, fontset);
    } else {
        if (!(xfont = XLoadQueryFont(dpy, fontname))
                && !(xfont = XLoadQueryFont(dpy, "fixed")))
            INIT_ERR("error loading font for bar\n")
        width_c = XTextWidth(xfont, "0", 1);
        XFreeFont(dpy, xfont);
    }

    free(fontname);
    return (width_p / width_c) - 2;
}

static int
get_block_size(void)
{
    if (statvfs("/", &root_fs.fs_stat) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error getting root file stats")

    return root_fs.fs_stat.f_bsize;
}

static int
get_dev_id(void)
{
    int index = if_nametoindex(WIFI_INTERFACE);
    if (!index)
        INIT_ERR("error finding index value for wireless interface")
    return index;
}

static int
get_consts(Display *dpy)
{
    if ((devidx = get_dev_id()) == 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error getting device id")
    if ((block_size = get_block_size()) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error getting block size")
    if ((bar_max_len = get_bar_max_len(dpy)) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error calculating max bar length")
    if ((cpu_ratio = get_cpu_ratio()) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error calculating cpu ratio")
    if ((temp_max = get_temp_max()) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error getting max temp")
    if ((fan_min = get_fan_min()) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error getting min fan speed")
    if ((fan_max = get_fan_max()) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error getting max fan speed")
    if ((screen_brightness_max = get_screen_brightness_max()) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error getting max screen brightness")
    if ((kbd_brightness_max = get_kbd_brightness_max()) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error getting max keyboard brightness")
    if ((vol_range = get_vol_range()) < 0 )
        INIT_ERR("error getting volume range")

    return 0;
}

static int
init(Display *dpy, Window root)
{
    time_t curr_time;

    if ((temp_list = populate_temp_list(temp_list, "input")) == NULL)
        INIT_ERR("error opening temperature directory")
    populate_tm_struct();
    if (get_consts(dpy) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error intializing constants")
    make_urls();

    get_TODO();
    get_log_status();
    get_weather();
    get_backup_status();
    get_portfolio_value();
    get_wifi_status();
    get_time();

    get_network_usage();
    get_disk_usage();
    get_memory();
    get_cpu_load();
    get_cpu_usage();
    get_cpu_temp();
    get_fan_speed();

    get_brightness();
    get_volume();
    get_battery();

    time(&curr_time);
    if (format_string(dpy, root) < 0)
        INIT_ERR("error format_string() in init()")

    return 0;
}

int
main(void)
{
    static Display *dpy;
    static int screen;
    static Window root;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    root = RootWindow(dpy, screen);

    if (init(dpy, root) < 0)
        strcpy(statusbar_string, "Initialization failed. Check log for details.");
    else {
        switch (loop(dpy, root)) {
            case 1:
                strcpy(statusbar_string, "Error getting weather. Loop broken. Check log for details.");
                break;
            case 2:
                strcpy(statusbar_string, "Error getting WiFi info. Loop broken. Check log for details.");
                break;
            default:
                strcpy(statusbar_string, "Loop broken. Check log for details.");
                break;
        }
    }

    XStoreName(dpy, root, statusbar_string);
    XFlush(dpy);

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @HildeN, FYI I suggest you to check [slstatus](https://git.suckless.org/slstatus) directory structure. It seems to be way cleaner.

Comment: @sineemore, Looking at it right now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of code there, I'll just pick a few things.

- Return value from `main` should be `0` on success and then something
  else in case any of those error cases were hit.  In general it makes
  sense to keep to this convention so that e.g. typical shell operations
  that operate on the exit status will work.
- There are a couple of hard-coded field lengths, in addition those
  lengths are not defined as constants, so might easily get out of sync.
  I'd suggest at least defining and reusing constants for the lengths,
  or using the `sizeof` operator consistently on the actual arrays where
  possible.
- There are a few `strcpy`s where it's not immediately clear to me that
  they're safe (won't overwrite more memory than was allocated) - using
  `strncpy` might be a good habit.  For `format_string` that goes
  doubly as it's in no way obvious that this function is safe.
- `get_cpu_usage` supports exactly four CPU(core)s - for a general
  purpose program it'd be much better if it could deal with any number
  of them, or at least up to a fixed maximum.
- I guess for the wifi interface and some of the other paths it might be
  fine to make them a configuration value, since auto-detecting the
  intended interface might be a hassle.  Then again, as a critique I'd
  much rather see those discovered on startup than having to supply them
  myself.
- `bool` as well as `int` are used to indicate a boolean value, I'd pick
  and stick with one or the other really (apart from `main` and library
  functions of course).
- `make_urls` isn't necessary, you can concatenate strings with the
  preprocessor/via normal string constants as in
  `#define WEATHER_URL "http...id=" LOCATION "&appid=" KEY "&units=imperial"`.
- I don't even have most of the headers under the wifi block installed -
  in the interest of greater portability I'd lean on the side of using
  an external program here (and thus reusing code) and just fork a new
  process for that.  A quick search suggests a few ways to get the wifi
  SSID for example.  I actually did the same as you with ALSA though to
  display volume, but IMO that's more portable as well.  Similarly
  there's something to be said to do the for other things here too, like
  a combination of `curl` and e.g. `jq` to do JSON parsing and so on.
  Of course that all depends on your objectives.
- Edit: Come to think of it, I had to check the linked list again:
  Good that it uses the embedding pattern, but in `add_link` the code
  should really not be traversing the list till the end on every call.
  Either keep the list in reverse order (not checked if that's viable),
  or just add them up like a stack and reverse the list in one single
  loop at the end.  That might not matter in a small program, just in
  general.

So, overall looks good, in particular the error macros are a really
nice touch.

Comment: Your feedback is awesome. I really appreciate your taking the time to read through my code. I'm going to start digesting it now.